# How to notify the user in case of unsubmitted change in QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using `QDataWidgetMapper` to display values in a model. I set its submit policy to be `ManualSubmit` so that users won't accidentally put in wrong values. But I also want to warn the user about unsubmitted change if he/she selects another row without saving. I have consulted the documentation and the Internet, but it seems that no signals are emitted prior to change in selection, nor is there any API querying the dirty status of the `QDataWidgetMapper`, which makes my task seemingly impossible. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you copy the model and use the copy with `QDataWidgetMapper` and 'autoSubmit'?  Then you could listen for changes via the mapper and only move data back from the source model on form submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable in the submit slot whose value you can monitor when the user selects another row.

Let value of that variable be x.
When user selects another row, fire a signal whose slot will check whether [some text has changed or appeared in the text box of previous row](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#signals) *&& if that variable is still x*.

If the variable is still `x` that would mean user didn't click the submit button.
When user clicks the submit button, let the variable be `y`.

Comment: If I have to keep track of which one has changed, that defeats the purpose of `QDataWidgetMapper`.